# JQGrid - How to use EditUrl

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm trying to use a delete button to delete selected items from a JQGrid. The javascript code looks as below

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MyGridServlet?action=fetchData',
        editurl:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MyGridServlet?action=deleteData',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
        colModel :[ 
            {name:'invid', index:'invid', width:55,editable:true, editrules:{required:true,number:true}}, 
            {name:'invdate', index:'invdate', width:90, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}}, 
            {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:80, align:'right',editable:true, editrules:{required:true,number:true}}, 
            {name:'tax', index:'tax', width:80, align:'right',editable:true, editrules:{required:true,number:true}}, 
            {name:'total', index:'total', width:80, align:'right',editable:true, editrules:{required:true,number:true}}, 
            {name:'note', index:'note', width:150, sortable:false,editable:true, editrules:{required:false}} 
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        multiselect: true,
        loadonce: true,
        height: '100%',
        weight:'100%',
        rowNum:10,
        rowTotal: 2000,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        sortname: 'invid',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        scrollable: false,
        caption: 'My first grid',
        ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
            grid.jqGrid('editGridRow',rowid, editParam);
            return;
        }
    });                 
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,del:false,edit:true});
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
}); 
function deleteData(){
    alert("testing");
    var gr = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if( gr != null ) jQuery("#list").jqGrid('delGridRow',gr,{reloadAfterSubmit:false});
    else alert("Please Select Row to delete!");
}
```

The Servlet Code looks like below

```
    package com.test.servlets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class MyGridServlet extends HttpServlet {

    /** 
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            if (request.getParameter("action").equals("deleteData")) {
                response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
                String status = request.getParameter("status");
                String rows = request.getParameter("rows");
                String page = request.getParameter("page");
                int totalPages = 0;
                int totalCount = 15;
                if (totalCount > 0) {
                    if (totalCount % Integer.parseInt(rows) == 0) {
                        totalPages = totalCount / Integer.parseInt(rows);
                    } else {
                        totalPages = (totalCount / Integer.parseInt(rows)) + 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    totalPages = 0;
                }
                out.print("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n");
                out.print("<rows>");
                out.print("<page>" + request.getParameter("page") + "</page>");
                out.print("<total>" + totalPages + "</total>");
                out.print("<records>" + 15 + "</records>");
                int srNo = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    out.print("<row id='" + i + "'>");
                    out.print("<cell>" + request.getParameter("invid") + "</cell>");
                    out.print("<cell>Nov 15, 2011</cell>");
                    out.print("<cell>00$</cell>");
                    out.print("<cell>0$</cell>");
                    out.print("<cell>00$</cell>");
                    out.print("<cell>000</cell>");
                    out.print("</row>");
                }
                out.print("</rows>");

        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
 }
```

Now when I run this, this works till the Delete Prompt i.e. when user clicks the Delete button, onclick the `deleteData()` function gets invoked, the alert "testing" gets displayed and the confirmation for delete box also pops up and when the user confirms for delete, I can see the error `parsererror Status: 'parsererror'. Error code: 200` on screen.

What I'm trying to achieve is that on button click, the servlet should get invoked, in the servlet, I want to delete data from db and then return. How can I achieve this ? Also what should the Servlet return in response ?

Answer (score 1):

What does the ajax response look like from the server (use Chrome network tab or Firebug to view it)?  Is there actually a request being generated?  The servlet does not need to return anything for the editurl - the response really should be blank. jqGrid should reload the data from your "url" source to rebuild the grid, post-delete.

Comment: I removed the code that was creating a return xml from servlet on delete, now on delete when the servlet gets invoked, nothing is done in servlet, it should just return empty. But now nothing happens, the delete confirmation screen just hangs when i click on 'Delete'. Im not able to attach a screenshot but it just hangs there with the promt. Is there some example where i can refer to a good edit, delete and add functionality ? I have seen the jqgrid demo at trirand but that does not cover the servlet processing.... appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm not seeing your screenshot.  Once again, though - have you looked to see if the ajax request is actually being made?  Inspect your network traffic and see what's going on there, and report back please.

Comment: Im not able to attach screenshot as im a new user here... Is there some example where i can refer to a good edit, delete and add functionality ? I have seen the jqgrid demo at trirand but that does not cover the servlet processing.... appreciate any help.

Comment: Jake - I fixed the above issue by making an explicit ajax call from the button function. I was able to pass a value to my servlet and get the row deleted. I'm now trying to figure out how to retrieve all the selected rows, put in a loop and make ajax calls to delete them.

Comment: Probably should start a new question to address that.